# How to change the content of a JavaScript function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, canvas

The problem I have is that I am trying to change the image from a canvas tag when the client selects a different radio button.

The content of the canvas is stored in the database with the code of the draw which I got from Illustrator (a lot of code).

What I did first was to change the data from a script tag by id where I created the function that paints the canvas.

It worked well, it painted the draw correctly. The problem is that when I select another radio button, even when the content of the script changes and so does the function, it draws the same painting and not the updated one.

I think that this happens because JavaScript does not update the content of the function after this has been already called once. Am I wrong?

If it is the problem I have, is it possible to change the content of the function after it has been called?

This is the html code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvasDel" height="600" width="600" style="max-width:600px;"></canvas>
<script id="scriptjs"></script>
```

This is the JavaScript one when I click on the radio button:

```
function mostrarCanvas(codiprd, codicol) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxcanvas.php",
        data: {
            codiprd: codiprd,
            codicol: codicol
        },
        success: function (datos) {

            $('#scriptjs').html(datos);

            var canvasDel = document.getElementById("myCanvasDel");
            var ctxDel = canvasDel.getContext("2d");
            drawDel(ctxDel);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Ha habido un error: ' + e);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And this is the PHP that the ajax file calls:

```
$codiprd=$_POST['codiprd'];
$codicol=$_POST['codicol'];
$querycnv = "SELECT CANVAS "
        . "FROM MYTABLE PC "
        . "WHERE PC.CODIPRD=$codiprd AND PC.CODICOL=$codicol "
        . "GROUP BY PC.CODIPRD,PC.CODICOL;";

$resultcnv = mysqli_query($conn, $querycnv)or die(mysqli_error());
$canvas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcnv);

echo $canvas['CANVAS']);
```

Comment: No, "function content" doesn't change. A function is a function which does something according to its source code. A function can take *parameters*, variables, which you can use in the code to influence what it's doing exactly.

Comment: What is the contemts of the #scriptsjs element? Is that a <script> tag whose contents you are trying to change?

Comment: @mcgraphix Yes, that's it. It's an empty script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the function as you can redefine any varible.

```
function foo(){
    console.log("blah");
}
```

can be redefined with

```
foo = function(){
    console.log("blah,blah");
}
```

A function is just another object, and thus can be used like any referenced variable.

You can create a function from a string

```
var funcStr = 'return "hi there!";';  // the function body
var func = new Function(funcStr);  // create the function
console.log(func()); // >> hi there
```

You set arguments with

```
var funcStr = 'return "hi there " + name;';  // the function body with arg name
var func = new Function("name",funcStr);  // create the function with the argument name
console.log(func("Me")); // >> hi there Me
```

You can also create a script tag and add it to the DOM

```
    var scriptSource = "//Source code;\nconsole.log("Script run");"
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = true;
    script.text = scriptSource;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    // in time the console will read
    // >> Script run
```

You need to wait for the script to be parsed which will not happen until you exit the current execution. After the script has loaded, it is first parsed and then run. If you wish you can just have the function body in the script tag and let it run by itself.